# Problema con stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql

he estado dandole vueltas a este codigo y no hayo donde está el error:

```
DELIMITER //
create PROCEDURE sp_reportes(
    in seleccion int,
    in anio int,
    in mes int,
    in id_personal int,
    in fechaini date,
    in fechafin date
    )
    BEGIN
        if (seleccion = 1) THEN
        BEGIN
            select 
                fecha, 
                sum(aportes) aportes, 
                sum(salidas) salidas 
            from 
                (
                    select 
                        ap.fecha, 
                        ap.cantidad aportes, 
                        '' salidas 
                    from 
                        aportes ap 
                    union all
                    select 
                        sa.fecha, 
                        '' aportes, 
                        sa.cantidad 
                    from 
                        salidas sa 
                ) as dat 
                where 
                    if(anio=0,true,year(fecha)=anio)
                    and if(mes=0,true,month(fecha)=mes)
                group by
                    fecha;
        END
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

el error que me muestra es el siguiente:

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 36.

Lo que está exactamente en la línea 36 es:  "group by"

Comment: Si quitas el ; del group by ya intentaste con eso?

Comment: si, y sigue igual